# Opencv - Build Opencv failed (MacOSX)

Tags: java, c++, opencv, netbeans, homebrew

I installed opencv using homebrew. There's no jar file.  Can't seem to find the jar file. Tried downloading again - opencv 2.4.3, 2.4.7, 2.4.8. again tried to build but getting errors in the middle of building jar file.
I'm trying to make a OpenCV Java project in Netbeans. I tried to look for jar file. Since it's not there, I build the Opencv but getting error.

Trying this to build OpenCv jar:

```
$ cd opencv-2.4.7

$ mkdir build

$ cd build/

$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -D WITH_CUDA=ON .. 

$make -j4 

$ make install
```

I'm on MacOSX 10.8.5.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error I'm getting is :

```
BUILD FAILED

/Users/ih/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/build.xml:9: Class not
 found: javac1.8

 Total time: 0 seconds make[2]: *** [bin/opencv-247.jar] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [modules/java/CMakeFiles/opencv_java.dir/all] Error 2
 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... Linking CXX shared
 library ../../lib/cv2.so [ 89%] Built target opencv_python make: ***
 [all] Error 2
```

Just to confirm I do have javac installed.

Comment: ... and the error is ?

Comment: I added a link. Here I pasted the error I got when building it. @berak

Comment: oh, no put it here, append it to your q.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CMake instead of Homebrew (follow [this](https://sites.google.com/site/yonasstephenfyp2013/updates/tutorialinstallingopencvonmacosxmountainlion) tutorial).

Regards.

Comment: Hi, I managed to finally built it. thank you! I was wondering where is the .jar file? I went into OpenCV-2.4.3/build/bin but it's not there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem previously, since my previous jdk used is 1.8. Then I solved it by set the jvm to the lower version.
See what are the available versions:

> /usr/libexec/java_home -V

for me, my versions are listed as:

> Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
>
> 1.8.0_25, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" >/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
>   1.7.0_60, x86_64:  "Java SE 7" >/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
>   1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:  "Java SE 6" >/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Then I simply set the java version by set JAVA_HOME:

> export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_60`

Finally, the OpenCV installation went well!
Hope it helps!